# unity permission on maximize

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions, settings

**Scenario:** My app follows Android 6 permission guidelines, by suppressing Unity's permission requests at launch time. The user grants Location Permissions when needed.

In my manifest, I used:

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" />
```

If the user goes to setting and turns the permission off while the app runs in the background, and then returns to the app, the app attempts to relaunch. However, before showing the splash screen, the screen goes white, and several copies of the same Location Permission prompt overlap each other. The number of prompts equals the number of times the app has been launched on the device.

If permission are turn off while the app is not running, the app runs normal when restarted.

Video demonstration: https://youtu.be/iHiMC-H6n3o